# leaflet map with multiple marker on exact same position

Tags: leaflet

We're using Leaflet to display markers from GeoJSON and some of them are located in the same position making it difficult to dismabiguate and select specific markers.

I know there is a [plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) to help to cluster and disambiguate the markers, but it's not a solution for me because I draw lines above the markers.

Is there a way to 'spiderfy'/show multiple markers without clustering?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet

Comment: I'm gonna say https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Marker.Stack

Comment: One solution could be to just rotate the markers with CSS; 30 degrees in each direction